# Are there still servers up to play Battlefield 2142 online?

Tags: battlefield-2142

I have just found my old pc game Battlefield 2142(from 2008). Can I still play this game on-line?(I will first have to find serial, so I can't just check)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In fact, I re-installed 2142 today and was plesantly surpised to find a large number of server still up and running. You will have to download the latest patch, 1.50, which is over 500MB and may take a while to download. There is a 1.51 Beta but not sure how many server support it.

Dec 2011 - now that Battefield 3 has been released there are only around 20-30 servers online with varying numbers of players. It's best to find one server and stay on that one, then you get to know the "regulars" and it's quite enjoyable with a good squad.

Comment: are people still palying this game or is it a ghost town?

Comment: there are plenty of servers and plenty of people online. When I launched the server browser for the first time there were at least 10 full servers with the full 64 playes in. You'll be plesantly surpised.

Answer (score 2):

I only reqularly see between 2 and 8 servers online any more, but it is playable on good nights when there are enough people logged in.

Answer (score 1):

There is not nearly as many as there used to be, and the number seems to drop each week.  However, it is worth installing and upgrading to 1.50 as there are still are several decent ones.  One nice side effect is you get to see a lot of the same players.

Comment: How long do you have to wait to play on-line?(i think it needs min. 16 players, right?)

Comment: No you can play with less than 16.  Most of the time I think 8 is the min, but there typically is a server with 30-60.